# Return the Summed Value of an Expression Column (Using expression builder)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that currently sums the total stock on hand (SOH) for an item from multiple storage locations then using an expression multiplies the SOH by the average cost to give a total SOH value for each line item.

I would like to take this calculation 1 step further and have the query return the total summed value for all the records returned in the original query.

Is it possible to sum the SoH_Value_VND expression column within the same query?

In the final output I do not require to see the data shown below, only the total value for the group is required.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Query result]

[image: Query Expression Builder]

[image: Query SQL]

Comment: I guess you mean _another_ query, not the same. Then just sum on SoH_Value_VND and leave out grouping in anything else than the group.

Comment: Please post attempted query in body of question and not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an additional column with

```
SUM(SoH_Value_VND) OVER () AS "total sum"
```

The `OVER` clause with empty `()` will apply the `SUM` to all rows.
I don't know, if MS-Access supports the `OVER` clause though.
For example in the query

```
SELECT 
  SoH, 
  averageCost, 
  SoH_Value_VND, 
  SUM(SoH_Value_VND) OVER ()
FROM whatever_table_or_view_or_join
```

Another idea is to just write a sub select, which returns a single column value (1 row with 1 column) from a select query like so:

```
SELECT 
  SoH, 
  averageCost, 
  SoH_Value_VND, 
  (SELECT SUM(SoH_Value_VND) FROM wherever_you_got_it)
FROM whatever_table_or_view_or_join
```

If you want to do further calculations with the rows and the sum, you may also need to use `GROUP BY` maybe.